# what is the difference between datafile and datablock in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

i am trying to know about is there any difference in 
**data block** which is a Smallest logical unit of data storage in Oracle Database.

and the **data file** which is A physical file on disk that was created by Oracle Database and contains the data for a database.

can anybody please tell me that what exactly difference between the data file and the data block

Answer (score 2):

A *data file* is a file where Oracle stores the data for tables, indexes etc. In order for Oracle to manage the data stored in this file, Oracle splits the file into evenly sized chunks that are called *data block*.

So *data blocks* are purely an Oracle thing, while a *data file* is also an OS thing.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, Oracle **logically** stores data in **data blocks** and **physically** in **data files**. As Oracle documents it, data block is the finest level of granularity. Data blocks are also called **logical blocks, Oracle blocks, or pages**.